# Submitting iOS 9 sdk version to Apple itunes connect error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios9

I would like to send a beta test to external users for iOS 9 but iTunes connect is not accepting SDK versions over 8.4. Can someone help here. The changes I need to make will affect 1/3 of my code.

Here's the error:

> Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in SwiftSupport/libswiftCore.dylib is 9.0
>   which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that until a few weeks before iOS 9 is released. You can use Ad Hoc distribution: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I went through the document and I know I can doad hoc but we want to utilize test flight external to reach 750 users. May I ask you, where did you find the information regarding iTunes connect accepting beta builds, with iOS9, a few weeks before actual release date? At the end of the day I need to give my managers a statement from apple in this regard and I couldn't find that in the document.

Comment: I've not yet found any info, but it's been like that before. That is no guarantee that it will stay that way of course. If you log to iTunes Connect the news item on the top says "TestFlight for iOS 9 Beta Builds.
You can now invite your internal testers to test apps that you’ve built for iOS 9 beta.". They specifically mention _internal_ testers, so that's a strong clue that the there's no way to distribute to the (up to 1000) external testers.